# Free Pascal terminal IDE fp seems not to compile with fpc

Tags: freepascal

I got my Free Pascal code here -

```
program HelloWorld;
uses crt;

begin
   writeln('Hello, World!');
   readkey;
end.
```

and saved it into `helloworld.pas`. When I compile it with `fpc`, everything goes right and the compiling succeeds. So I tried `fp`, the IDE that comes with `fpc` and also uses this very compiler. But here, IDE internal compiling fails. Main error message:

```
helloworld.pas(2,6) Fatal: Can't find unit crt used by HelloWorld
```

Comment: For what I remember, the fp IDE uses an internal compiler. You should navigate the menus of the ide, and set a few options to make the compiler find the crt unit.

Comment: In addition to Linuxfan:  The textmode IDE usually automagically picks up the RTL directory, but not the rest. In older versions Crt was in the RTL, but since 3.0 it isn't anymore, so while this might have worked in older versions, now it requires setting paths like linuxfan says.